# List of buttons and label in java actionListener

Tags: jpanel, jbutton, jlabel, actionlistener, jlist

So i have a JList, and each row is a JButton followed by a jLabel. And what i need to do is when i click on the button it call a function, but right now wherever i click on the row, it calls another function.

The problem is that it is going inside the function of the listselectionlistener. So the button listener is never called. I've tried to remove the list listener and just have the button one, it did not work. I was thinking maybe in the listener of the list, i could verify where the click was done, but i dont think its the right way of doing it.

Any idea?

Here is how i defined my class

```
public class SelectScheduleUI extends JPanel implements ListCellRenderer<JPanel>, ListSelectionListener, ActionListener
```

Here is the code when i create part of my frame.

```
m_Schedules = new DefaultListModel<JPanel>();
m_SchedulesList = new JList<JPanel>(m_Schedules);

m_SchedulesList.addListSelectionListener(this);
```

and later when i add each element of the list.

```
JPanel schedulePanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

JButton enabledLabel = new JButton();   
enabledLabel.setBounds(0, 0, ICON_WIDTH, ICON_HEIGHT);
enabledLabel.setBorder(null);
enabledLabel.addActionListener((ActionListener) this);
schedulePanel.add(enabledLabel, c, LABEL_ICON);

JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setText(p_SchedulerName);
label.setBounds(0, 0, LABEL_NAME_WIDTH, ICON_HEIGHT);
schedulePanel.add(label, c, LABEL_NAME);

m_Schedules.addElement(schedulePanel);
```

I have a dummy procedure for the on button click event

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    //Execute when button is pressed
    System.out.println("You clicked the button");
}
```

And here is the listener for the list

```
@Override
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getValueIsAdjusting() == false)
    {
        //if the user didn't select anything, or is in the 
        //  process of selecting multiple items, don't update
        if(m_SchedulesList.getSelectedIndex() == -1 || 
                m_SchedulesList.getSelectedIndices().length > 1)
        {
            return;
        }
        m_Selector.onScheduleSelect(m_Schedules.get(m_SchedulesList.getSelectedIndex()).getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out a way of doing this, instead of using a JList that will include the JLabel and the JButton. I just used a JTable, first column being the label, and the second being a checkbox(in my case I needed something to turn on\off something from the list).

And with that JTable I needed the OnColumnClick event and OnRowClick event. To be able to call the same button multiple time i just select the other column of the same row inside OnColumnClick.